# Windows 10 toolbars. Do more than show a folders contents

Tags: date, windows-10, taskbar

I would like to show the date on my windows taskbar. I would also like to keep small icons. I had a think about how to solve this and noticed the new(ish) 'toolbar' featuer in windows 10. Lenovo porducts have a 'lenovo vantage' toolbar that shows the battery percentage and opens a menu when you click it so it is presumably possible to make something like this.

So is there a way to make a toolbar display information and not just the contents of a file?

Is there another way to do this? (I'd quite like to write it myself as a learning exercise but if that is very difficult and there is an existing solution that would also be good)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock

This link gives a program that does it. I'd still be interested in a way of doing it myself but this works.